# Rails 4.2 Polymorphic associations, association name not resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I created the migration according the polymorphic rails cookbook. The models have the following relations

```
class TeachingAssistant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ta_type, polymorphic: true
end

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teaching_assistants, as: :ta_type
end
```

In the rails console i am able to do the following

```
t = TeachingAssistant.create name: 'name' 
u = University.create name: 'hogwarth' 
t.update ta_type: u 
University.last.teaching_assistants.last
```

But why is it not possible to use the `as: :ta_type` association name directly;

```
University.last.ta_type
```

results for example in undefined method  for `ta_type`. But typing

```
University.last.ta_type
```

and  tab-completing  returns the following list

```
University.last.ta_type    
University.last.ta_type=           
University.last.ta_type_id        
University.last.ta_type_id=                   
University.last.ta_type_id?                  
University.last.ta_type_id_before_type_cast   
University.last.ta_type_id_came_from_user?      
University.last.ta_type_id_change              
University.last.ta_type_id_changed?            
University.last.ta_type_id_was       
....
```

Why is this not possible? Is it by design or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? After all `ta_type` for any `TeachingAssistant` instance associated with a `University` is always going to be `University`. What is your motivation for this?

Comment: Could you show us your migration?